# Python index a list where a regex matches

Tags: python, regex, list

Again recognizing that this is similar to a few other questions on SO but which I haven't been able to convert for my purposes. eg. with the snippet below

```
import re
a = ['rhubarb','plain custard','jam','vanilla custard','pie','cheesecake']
s = re.compile('custard')
```

I'd like to be able to get a list

`[2,4]`

which is the index of the two `custard` strings. I thought the question below would help but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply it here.

[Python equivalent of which() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207014/python-equivalent-of-which-in-r)

Comment: Are you *sure* you want `[2,4]` or do you want `[1,3]`? Indexes in python start at 0. So if you're looking to use those values to index into the original list, they will be wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> a = ['rhubarb','plain custard','jam','vanilla custard','pie','cheesecake']
>>> [i for i, s in enumerate(a, start=1) if re.search('custard', s)]
[2, 4]
```

**note** Python uses 0-index so I added the `start=1` parameter to `enumerate`. In practice you should leave off `start=1` to have the default `start=0`.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about that extra parameter. +1