# Python Pandas: Get index of rows where column matches certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Given a DataFrame with a column "BoolCol", we want to find the indexes of the DataFrame in which the values for "BoolCol" == True

I currently have the iterating way to do it, which works perfectly:

```py
for i in range(100,3000):
    if df.iloc[i]['BoolCol']== True:
         print i,df.iloc[i]['BoolCol']
```

But this is not the correct pandas way to do it. After some research, I am currently using this code:

```py
df[df['BoolCol'] == True].index.tolist()
```

This one gives me a list of indexes, but they don't match, when I check them by doing:

```py
df.iloc[i]['BoolCol']
```

The result is actually False!!

Which would be the correct pandas way to do this?

Answer (score 787, accepted):

`df.iloc[i]` returns the `ith` row of `df`. `i` does not refer to the index label, `i` is a 0-based index.

In contrast, **the attribute `index` returns actual index labels**, not numeric row-indices:

```
df.index[df['BoolCol'] == True].tolist()
```

or equivalently,

```
df.index[df['BoolCol']].tolist()
```

You can see the difference quite clearly by playing with a DataFrame with
a non-default index that does not equal to the row's numerical position:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BoolCol': [True, False, False, True, True]},
       index=[10,20,30,40,50])

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
   BoolCol
10    True
20   False
30   False
40    True
50    True

[5 rows x 1 columns]

In [54]: df.index[df['BoolCol']].tolist()
Out[54]: [10, 40, 50]
```

---

**If you want to use the index**,

```
In [56]: idx = df.index[df['BoolCol']]

In [57]: idx
Out[57]: Int64Index([10, 40, 50], dtype='int64')
```

**then you can select the rows using `loc` instead of `iloc`**:

```
In [58]: df.loc[idx]
Out[58]: 
   BoolCol
10    True
40    True
50    True

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

---

Note that **`loc` can also accept boolean arrays**:

```
In [55]: df.loc[df['BoolCol']]
Out[55]: 
   BoolCol
10    True
40    True
50    True

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

---

**If you have a boolean array, `mask`, and need ordinal index values, you can compute them using `np.flatnonzero`**:

```
In [110]: np.flatnonzero(df['BoolCol'])
Out[112]: array([0, 3, 4])
```

Use `df.iloc` to select rows by ordinal index:

```
In [113]: df.iloc[np.flatnonzero(df['BoolCol'])]
Out[113]: 
   BoolCol
10    True
40    True
50    True
```

Answer (score 50):

Can be done using numpy where() function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [716]: df = pd.DataFrame({"gene_name": ['SLC45A1', 'NECAP2', 'CLIC4', 'ADC', 'AGBL4'] , "BoolCol": [False, True, False, True, True] },
       index=list("abcde"))

In [717]: df
Out[717]: 
  BoolCol gene_name
a   False   SLC45A1
b    True    NECAP2
c   False     CLIC4
d    True       ADC
e    True     AGBL4

In [718]: np.where(df["BoolCol"] == True)
Out[718]: (array([1, 3, 4]),)

In [719]: select_indices = list(np.where(df["BoolCol"] == True)[0])

In [720]: df.iloc[select_indices]
Out[720]: 
  BoolCol gene_name
b    True    NECAP2
d    True       ADC
e    True     AGBL4
```

Though you don't always need index for a match, but incase if you need:

```
In [796]: df.iloc[select_indices].index
Out[796]: Index([u'b', u'd', u'e'], dtype='object')

In [797]: df.iloc[select_indices].index.tolist()
Out[797]: ['b', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 48):

If you want to use your dataframe object only once, use:

```
df['BoolCol'].loc[lambda x: x==True].index
```

Answer (score 5):

First you may check `query` when the target column is type `bool`  (PS: about how to use it please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval/53779987#53779987) )

```
df.query('BoolCol')
Out[123]: 
    BoolCol
10     True
40     True
50     True
```

After we filter the original df by the Boolean column we can pick the index .

```
df=df.query('BoolCol')
df.index
Out[125]: Int64Index([10, 40, 50], dtype='int64')
```

---

Also pandas have `nonzero`, we just select the ***position*** of `True` row and using it slice the `DataFrame` or `index`

```
df.index[df.BoolCol.values.nonzero()[0]]
Out[128]: Int64Index([10, 40, 50], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple way is to reset the index of the DataFrame prior to filtering:

```
df_reset = df.reset_index()
df_reset[df_reset['BoolCol']].index.tolist()
```

Bit hacky, but it's quick!

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use `pipe()` to pipe the indexing of the index of `BoolCol`. In terms of performance, it's as efficient as the canonical indexing using `[]`.<sup>1</sup>

```py
df['BoolCol'].pipe(lambda x: x.index[x])
```

This is especially useful if `BoolCol` is actually the result of multiple comparisons and you want to use method chaining to put all methods in a pipeline.

For example, if you want to get the row indexes where `NumCol` value is greater than 0.5, `BoolCol` value is True and the product of `NumCol` and `BoolCol` values is greater than 0, you can do so by evaluating an expression via `eval()` and call `pipe()` on the result to perform the indexing of the indexes.<sup>2</sup>

```py
df.eval("NumCol > 0.5 and BoolCol and NumCol * BoolCol >0").pipe(lambda x: x.index[x])
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: The following benchmark used a dataframe with 20mil rows (on average filtered half of the rows) and retrieved their indexes. The method chaining via `pipe()` does very well compared to the other efficient options.

```py
n = 20_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({'NumCol': np.random.rand(n).astype('float16'), 
                   'BoolCol': np.random.default_rng().choice([True, False], size=n)})

%timeit df.index[df['BoolCol']]
# 181 ms ± 2.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df['BoolCol'].pipe(lambda x: x.index[x])
# 181 ms ± 1.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df['BoolCol'].loc[lambda x: x].index
# 297 ms ± 7.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

<sup>2</sup>: For a 20 mil row dataframe constructed in the same way as in <sup>1</sup>) for the benchmark, you will find that the method proposed here is the fastest option. It performs better than bitwise-operator chaining because by design, `eval()` performs multiple operations on a large dataframe faster than vectorized Python operations and it is more memory efficient than `query()` because unlike `query()`, `eval().pipe(...)` doesn't need to create a copy of the sliced dataframe to get its index.

Answer (score 1):

I extended this question that is how to gets the `row`, `column`and `value` of all matches value?

here is solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def search_coordinate(df_data: pd.DataFrame, search_set: set) -> list:
    nda_values = df_data.values
    tuple_index = np.where(np.isin(nda_values, [e for e in search_set]))
    return [(row, col, nda_values[row][col]) for row, col in zip(tuple_index[0], tuple_index[1])]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_datas = [['cat', 'dog', ''],
                  ['goldfish', '', 'kitten'],
                  ['Puppy', 'hamster', 'mouse']
                  ]
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(test_datas)
    print(df_data)
    result_list = search_coordinate(df_data, {'dog', 'Puppy'})
    print(f"\n\n{'row':<4} {'col':<4} {'name':>10}")
    [print(f"{row:<4} {col:<4} {name:>10}") for row, col, name in result_list]
```

Output:

```
          0        1       2
0       cat      dog        
1  goldfish           kitten
2     Puppy  hamster   mouse


row  col        name
0    1           dog
2    0         Puppy
```

Comment: Without explicitly using numpy by using boolean dataframe: https://thispointer.com/python-find-indexes-of-an-element-in-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 1):

For known index candidate that we interested, a faster way by not checking the whole column can be done like this:

```py
np.array(index_slice)[np.where(df.loc[index_slice]['column_name'] >= threshold)[0]]
```

Full comparison:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index_slice = list(range(50,150)) # know index location for our inteterest
data = np.zeros(10000)
data[(index_slice)] = np.random.random(len(index_slice))

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column_name': data},
)

threshold = 0.5
```

```py
%%timeit
np.array(index_slice)[np.where(df.loc[index_slice]['column_name'] >= threshold)[0]]
# 600 µs ± 1.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
[i for i in index_slice if i in df.index[df['column_name'] >= threshold].tolist()]
# 22.5 ms ± 29.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The way it works is like this:

```py
# generate Boolean satisfy condition only in sliced column
df.loc[index_slice]['column_name'] >= threshold

# convert Boolean to index, but start from 0 and increment by 1
np.where(...)[0]

# list of index to be sliced
np.array(index_slice)[...]
```

Note:
It needs to be noted that `np.array(index_slice)` can't be substituted by `df.index` due to `np.where(...)[0]` indexing `start from 0 and increment by 1`, but you can make something like `df.index[index_slice]`. And I think this is not worth the hassle if you just do it one time with small number of rows.