# How to get the index of one element in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

if dataframe df have two columns['A','B'],and i know in columns 'A' have one  element 'hello',how can i get the index of 'hello'?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800169/python-pandas-get-index-of-rows-which-column-matches-certain-value) what you are looking for?

Comment: in dataframe which function  can get  element index  if i know the element?

Comment: i create a pandas dataframe ,the values of  the dataframe get from HDF5 file,dataframe have columns['date','contract','isin','volumn','opneinterest'] ,if i know in column('isin') hava  element 'A0901' ,how can i get the volumn,opneinterest of  'A0901' ? thank for any help