# Get index of rows which column matches certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

There is a much similar post in the forum 
[POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800169/python-pandas-get-index-of-rows-which-column-matches-certain-value)
but i just cant figure out what how to do it in my exaple.

My code  now with explanation below

```
for i in dfuser.appid :
  print i
  d = dfbinary.loc[dfbinary['appid'] == i]
  print d
  glist = dfbinary.columns[dfbinary.loc[i]==1] 
  print glist
```

I have a dataframe with a list of users with their apps (dfuser) and i have another dataframe with the genres of all the apps(an app may have more than one genre). So i want to see which genre is more popular in each user.

My code is fine except that `glist` is not finding the appid that i want but finds the appid with index i. For example i=10 , so it will find the app that is at row 11(10).

This is what it prints

```
   10
   appid  Accounting  Action  Adventure  Animation&Modeling  AudioProduction... 
0   10.0         0.0     1.0        0.0                 0.0              0.0  
[1 rows x 23 columns]
Index([u'Action'], dtype='object')
```

(And this just happens to be correct)

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: @ians Well, i did show the example of code. As for results example, i need (for each user) `Action= 12 , Strategy= 7, Puzzle = 3`

Comment: @simon I dont know if the previous mention worked, so yeah, but thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Firstly whenever you have a loop with pandas you are probably doing it wrong!

You need to use merge to combine the two dataframes and select only the user and genre columns. It works just like SQL. Then you have a table keyed on user/genre. Now you can groupby("user").count(). No explicit loops.

Comment: Well of course i thought about that. Problem is that both files are big and the system can not compute such big file, saying that i merge them. Imagine 1million rows x 30 columns @simon

Comment: You don't need 30 columns though. So select what you need first then merge.

Comment: The genres are near 30, so yeah unfortunately i need them

Comment: i did merge the 2 files and i got a huge one. Now i am trying to do the groupby function but i get MemoryError. Is there maybe a way to iterate over user? Something like `for user in df.UserID`

Comment: I thought of chunksize but the number of rows for each user is not standard so maybe i would slice some users in half