# Pandas - find index of value anywhere in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python & Pandas.

I want to find the index of a certain value (let's say `security_id`) in my pandas dataframe, because that is where the columns start. 
(There is an unknown number of rows with irrelevant data above the columns, as well as a number of empty 'columns' on the left side.)

As far as I see, the [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method only returns a boolean on whether the value exists, not its index.

How do I find the index of this value?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that your DataFrame looks like the following :

```
      0       1            2      3    4
0     a      er          tfr    sdf   34
1    rt     tyh          fgd    thy  rer
2     1       2            3      4    5
3     6       7            8      9   10
4   dsf     wew  security_id   name  age
5   dfs    bgbf          121  jason   34
6  dddp    gpot         5754   mike   37
7  fpoo  werwrw          342   jack   31
```

Do the following :

```
for row in range(df.shape[0]): # df is the DataFrame
         for col in range(df.shape[1]):
             if df.get_value(row,col) == 'security_id':
                 print(row, col)
                 break
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a solution:) Though is the only way to find the value to iterate over both the rows and columns? Would there be a more efficient method?

Comment: No matter what you do, iteration will always be involved.  Either you will do it , else Pandas would do it. Internally iteration will always be involved. Moreover iteration stops once, you get the ID. The worst case would be when security_id is the bottom-right element of your DataFrame ( O(mn) ).  If the security_id is in the top-left half of the DataFrame, it won't be costly at all.

Comment: Moreover , you are asking for data cleaning. So, it is a cheap preprocessing step. Dont try to hyper-optimize everything. Premature optimization is the root of all evils. Remember.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I thought that might be the case (iteration in any case). Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 19):

Get the index for rows matching search term in all columns

```
search = 'security_id' 
df.loc[df.isin([search]).any(axis=1)].index.tolist()
```

Rows filtered for matching search term in all columns

```
search = 'search term' 
df.loc[df.isin([search]).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: This is probably the most performant answer, as it uses `.loc`. Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

value you are looking for is not duplicated:

```
poz=matrix[matrix==minv].dropna(axis=1,how='all').dropna(how='all')
value=poz.iloc[0,0]
index=poz.index.item()
column=poz.columns.item()
```

you can get its index and column

duplicated:

```
matrix=pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[1,np.NAN]],index=['q','g'],columns=['f','h'])
matrix
Out[83]: 
   f    h
q  1  1.0
g  1  NaN
poz=matrix[matrix==minv].dropna(axis=1,how='all').dropna(how='all')
index=poz.stack().index.tolist()
index
Out[87]: [('q', 'f'), ('q', 'h'), ('g', 'f')]
```

you will get a list

Answer (score 3):

A oneliner solution avoiding explicit loops...

- returning the entire row(s)

  df.iloc[np.flatnonzero((df=='security_id').values)//df.shape[1],:]
- returning row(s) and column(s)

  df.iloc[
    np.flatnonzero((df=='security_id').values)//df.shape[1],
    np.unique(np.flatnonzero((df=='security_id').values)%df.shape[1])
  ]

Answer (score 2):

I think this question may have been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800169/python-pandas-get-index-of-rows-which-column-matches-certain-value). The accepted answer is pretty comprehensive and should help you find the index of a value in a column.

Edit:
if the column that the value exists in is not known, then you could use:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[df[col] == 'security_id'].index.tolist()
```

Comment: At the given question the column is known. In my case I don't know in which column the value appears. But I agree that it gives the direction to the answer for my question

Comment: Ahh, apologies! you could loop over the Column's in the data frame and apply the answer linked above.
`for col in df.columns:
    df[df[col] == 'security_id'].index.tolist()`. This would also give you all occurrences of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Function finds the positions of a value in a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def pandasFindPositionsInDataframe(dfIn,findme):
    positions = []
    irow =0
    while ( irow < len(dfIn.index)):
        list_colPositions=dfIn.columns[dfIn.iloc[irow,:]==findme].tolist()   
        if list_colPositions != []:
            colu_iloc = dfIn.columns.get_loc(list_colPositions[0])
            positions.append([irow, colu_iloc])
        irow +=1

    return positions
```

Comment: How can this be made case insensitive?