# Pandas: reading Excel file starting from the row below that with a specific value

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Say I have the following Excel file:

```
    A      B     C
0   -      -     -
1   Start  -     -
2   3      2     4
3   7      8     4
4   11     2     17
```

I want to read the file in a dataframe making sure that I start to read it *below the row* where the `Start` value is.

**Attention**: the `Start` value is not always located in the same row, so if I were to use:

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:\Users\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsx')
df = xls.parse('Sheet1', skiprows=4, index_col=None)
```

this would fail as `skiprows` needs to be fixed. Is there any workaround to make sure that `xls.parse` finds the string value instead of the row number?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_excel('your/path/filename')
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386629/pandas-find-index-of-value-anywhere-in-dataframe) answer helps in finding the location of 'start' in the df

```
 for row in range(df.shape[0]): 

       for col in range(df.shape[1]):

           if df.iat[row,col] == 'start':

             row_start = row
             break
```

after having row_start you can use subframe of pandas

```
df_required = df.loc[row_start:]
```

And if you don't need the row containing 'start', just u increment row_start by 1

```
df_required = df.loc[row_start+1:]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you know the specific rows you are interested in, you can skip from the top using `skiprow` and then parse only the row (or rows) you want using `nrows` - see [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx', 'Sheet1', skiprows=2, nrows=3,)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pd.read_excel('C:\Users\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')` as it ignores empty excel cells.

Your DataFrame should then look like this:

```
    A      B     C
0   Start NaN   NaN
1   3      2     4
2   7      8     4
3   11     2     17
```

Then drop the first row by using

```
df.drop([0])
```

to get

```
    A      B     C
0   3      2     4
1   7      8     4
2   11     2     17
```

Comment: This is *almost* what I was looking for, in that my real Excel files have all sorts of information in the first `x` rows, so by doing `pd.read_excel('C:\Users\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')` I would pick that information up anyway. That's why I explicitly asked for ways in which a specific value could be looked up. Btw, thanks for your efforts, and I am going to upvote this.