# Scan columns for a keyword and extract all values in that column, if the keyword is found in that column

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

Thank you for spending your time here and helping out, I really appreciate it.

Currently, I have multiple excel files to loop through.

I am only looping through columns C:D. If the column has the keyword "Abbreviation", I want to extract all the values in that column. 
This is because my keyword could exist in either column C or D.

My columns will look something like this:
[image]

**OR**

[image]

After importing my excel files, here is how I loop through the columns that I want to scan through:

```
wb1 = load_workbook(join(dict_folder, file), data_only = True)
ws = wb1.active

for rowofcellobj in ws["C":"D"]:
   for cellobj in rowofcellobj:
      if cellobj.value == "Abbreviation":
        # extract all words in that column but Idk how to execute this step or if my above steps are correct
        if cellobj.value is not None:
        data = re.findall(r"\b\w+_.*?\w+|[A-Z]*$\b", str(cellobj.value))
        #filtering out blank rows here:
         if data != [ ]:
            if data != [' ']:
                 #extracting words from square brackets in list:
                      fields = data[0]
                      print(fields)
```

I am stuck at the area which I had commented above, saying that I'm not sure how to execute that step..

Comment: have you tried to use pandas read excel method, and than use pandas methods (looking for abbreviation column etc.)?

Comment: @EzerK no I have not, I have not tried using pandas at all since I do not have much knowledge on it and I had already started out with openpyxl. Could this be feasible with pandas? Cause I was worried that pandas is not able to read the columns unless it is the first row of the worksheet

Comment: This is a classic task for pandas (not yo say it's the only way) take a look at the pandas read excel docs

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Scan columns for a keyword and extract all values in that column

- Define start row, here `1`:

  ```
  min_row = 1
  min_col = None
  ```
- Loop all rows, starting at `min_row` and incrementing:

  ```
  for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=min_row, values_only=True):
      min_row += 1
  ```
- `try` to find the keyword in this `row`, `break` if found.
  As the `index` is `0-based`, `+1` to get the columns index `1-based`.

  ```
      try:
          min_col = row.index('Abbreviation') + 1
          break
      except:
          continue
  ```
- If found, loop all folloup rows, up to the end.

  > **Note**: You have not defined a **end condition**!

  ```
  if min_col is not None:
      for value in map(lambda x: x[0], 
                       sheet1.iter_rows(min_row=min_row, 
                                        min_col=min_col,                                  
                                        max_col=min_col,
                                        values_only=True)):
          print(value)
  ```

Comment: Hi! This seems to be working but it still prints out rows with None....

Answer (score 0):

Pandas solution, inspired by ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876077/pandas-reading-excel-file-starting-from-the-row-below-that-with-a-specific-valu))

Example file:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('tst.xlsx', usecols="C:D")
df = df.fillna('') 

for row in range(df.shape[0]): 
       for col in range(df.shape[1]):
           if df.iat[row,col] == 'Abbreviation':
             row_start = row
             col_required = col
             break

df = df.loc[row_start+1:, df.columns[col_required]]
df.replace(['','\s+'], np.nan, inplace=True, regex=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
9      sfsdfd
10    fgfg_ff
12        dfs
13        ddd
15      dd_hh
```

Comment: Hi Vladislav, thank you for your response! I have been trying to implement your code. But I cant even get to that step because when i run: `dict_folder = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Docs did/Requests"`
`for file in os.listdir(dict_folder):` `if re.search(r'\.xlsx$', file):` `df = pd.read_excel((file), usecols = "C:D")`  <<<<-------- these throws up an error in my Python saying "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xxxxx.xlsx'