# Python Pandas trasnpose DataFrame and rename columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's a simple DataFrame example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = dict(
    column1 = [1, 'a', 'foo'],
    column2 = [2, 'b', 'bar'],
    column3 = [3, 'c', 'baz'],
)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

with the output

```
  column1 column2 column3
0     1     2     3
1     a     b     c
2   foo   bar   baz
```

I want to transpose it and rename the columns:

```
df.do_some_manipulation('numbers', 'letters', 'words')
```

so the output would be

```
   numbers letters words
0        1       a   foo
1        2       b   bar
2        3       c   baz
```

Transpose method is not quite the thing, what should I do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.T
df.columns = ['numbers', 'letters', 'words']
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

A better option would be `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` with the `index` orient:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['numbers', 'letters', 'words'])

         numbers letters words
column1        1       a   foo
column2        2       b   bar
column3        3       c   baz
```

Comment: I just borrow your Q&A as reference , hope it is ok .https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119293/7964527

Comment: @W-B Please be free to do so :)