# Pandas Dataframe - Search by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the index is a timestamp.

```
DATE                VALOR   
2020-12-01 00:00:00 0.00635
2020-12-01 01:00:00 0.00941
2020-12-01 02:00:00 0.01151
2020-12-01 03:00:00 0.00281
2020-12-01 04:00:00 0.01080
... ...
2021-04-30 19:00:00 0.77059
2021-04-30 20:00:00 0.49285
2021-04-30 21:00:00 0.49057
2021-04-30 22:00:00 0.50339
2021-04-30 23:00:00 0.48792
```

I´m searching for a specific date

```
drop.loc['2020-12-01 04:00:00']

VALOR    0.0108
Name: 2020-12-01 04:00:00, dtype: float64
```

I want the return for the index of search above.

In this case is line 5. After I want to use this value to do a slice in the dataframe

```
drop[:5]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this might help you, please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800169/python-pandas-get-index-of-rows-which-column-matches-certain-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to subset `drop` up to index `'2020-12-01 04:00:00'`.

Then simply do this: `drop.loc[:'2020-12-01 04:00:00']`

No need to manually get the line number.

output:

```
                       VALOR
DATE                        
2020-12-01 00:00:00  0.00635
2020-12-01 01:00:00  0.00941
2020-12-01 02:00:00  0.01151
2020-12-01 03:00:00  0.00281
2020-12-01 04:00:00  0.01080
```

If you really want to get the position:

```
pos = drop.index.get_loc(key='2020-12-01 04:00:00')  ## returns: 4
drop[:pos+1]
```