# Pandas Equivalent of R's which()

Tags: python, pandas, logical-operators

Variations of this question have been asked before, I'm still having trouble understanding how  to actually slice a python series/pandas dataframe based on conditions that I'd like to set.

In R, what I'm trying to do is:

```
df[which(df[,colnumber] > somenumberIchoose),]
```

The which() function finds indices of row entries in a column in the dataframe which are greater than somenumberIchoose, and returns this as a vector.  Then, I slice the dataframe by using these row indices to indicate which rows of the dataframe I would like to look at in the new form.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in python? I've seen references to enumerate, which I don't fully understand after reading the documentation.  My sample in order to get the row indices right now looks like this:

```
indexfuture = [ x.index(), x in enumerate(df['colname']) if x > yesterday]
```

However, I keep on getting an invalid syntax error.  I can hack a workaround by for looping through the values, and manually doing the search myself, but that seems extremely non-pythonic and inefficient.

What exactly does enumerate() do?  What is the pythonic way of finding indices of values in a vector that fulfill desired parameters?

Note: I'm using Pandas for the dataframes

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of the error?

Comment: can you try: `[a.index() for (a, b) in enumerate(df['colname']) if b > yesterday]`

Comment: Just to be clear, pandas DataFrames can have all sorts of indices, not just integers. Do you only want integer indices, or the actual original row-indices?

Comment: Related question [Python equivalent of which() in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207014/python-equivalent-of-which-in-r)

Comment: The question asks about `which()` which returns a vector of indices in which some condition was met. The top answer is about boolean subsetting. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800169/python-pandas-get-index-of-rows-which-column-matches-certain-value) contains what I see as an actual equivalent to `which()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I may not understand clearly the question, but it looks like the response is easier than what you think:

using pandas DataFrame:

```
df['colname'] > somenumberIchoose
```

returns a pandas series with True / False values and the original index of the DataFrame.

Then you can use that boolean series on the original DataFrame and get the subset you are looking for:

```
df[df['colname'] > somenumberIchoose]
```

should be enough.

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Comment: `df[df['colname'] > somenumberIchoose].index` is the same as R which() function

Answer (score 8):

What what I know of R you might be more comfortable working with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) -- a scientific computing package similar to MATLAB.

If you want the indices of an array who values are divisible by two then the following would work.

```
arr = numpy.arange(10)
truth_table = arr % 2 == 0
indices = numpy.where(truth_table)
values = arr[indices]
```

It's also easy to work with multi-dimensional arrays

```
arr2d = arr.reshape(2,5)
col_indices = numpy.where(arr2d[col_index] % 2 == 0)
col_values = arr2d[col_index, col_indices]
```

Comment: +1 for a solution much closer to the R idiom. Also I don't like to turn everything into a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

`enumerate()` returns an iterator that yields an `(index, item)` tuple in each iteration, so you can't (and don't need to) call `.index()` again.

Furthermore, your list comprehension syntax is wrong:

```
indexfuture = [(index, x) for (index, x) in enumerate(df['colname']) if x > yesterday]
```

Test case:

```
>>> [(index, x) for (index, x) in enumerate("abcdef") if x > "c"]
[(3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f')]
```

Of course, you don't need to unpack the tuple:

```
>>> [tup for tup in enumerate("abcdef") if tup[1] > "c"]
[(3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f')]
```

unless you're only interested in the indices, in which case you could do something like

```
>>> [index for (index, x) in enumerate("abcdef") if x > "c"]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: So `Python : enumerate :: Ruby : each_with_index`?

Comment: There's no need to use `enumerate()`, it's inefficient, and even if there was a need, pd.DataFrame has `iterrows()` for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

And if you need an additional statement panda.Series allows you to do Operations between Series (+, -, /, , *).

Just multiplicate the indexes:

```
idx1 = df['lat'] == 49
idx2 = df['lng'] > 15 
idx = idx1 * idx2

new_df = df[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `enumerate`, I usually just use `.iteritems`. This saves a `.index()`. Namely,

```
[k for k, v in (df['c'] > t).iteritems() if v]
```

Otherwise, one has to do

```
df[df['c'] > t].index()
```

This duplicates the typing of the data frame name, which can be very long and painful to type.

Comment: I think it's just `df.index`, an attribute, not a function. I get an error that `'Int64Index' object is not callable` with `index()`. That said, both of these actually answer how one can do what `which()` does, so I like that!

Answer (score 0):

A nice simple and neat way of doing this is the following:

```
SlicedData1 = df[df.colname>somenumber]]
```

This can easily be extended to include other criteria, such as non-numeric data:

```
SlicedData2 = df[(df.colname1>somenumber & df.colname2=='24/08/2018')]
```

And so on...