# Find row number in column where it matches any other value in column of other dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arm_1_and_m1_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'record_id': [1, 4, 3, np.nan],
                   'two': [1, 2, np.nan , 4]
                 })

redcap_final_arm1_data = pd.DataFrame({ 'record_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, np.nan],
                   'two': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, np.nan]
                 })

ahk_ids_new=[]
for items in arm_1_and_m1_df['record_id'].iteritems():     # https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-iteritems/
    ahk_ids_new.append(np.where(redcap_final_arm1_data['record_id'] == items))    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519062/rs-which-and-which-min-equivalent-in-python
```

After running code above and after `ahk_ids_new` the content of `ahk_ids_new` is:

```
[(array([], dtype=int64),),
 (array([], dtype=int64),),
 (array([], dtype=int64),),
 (array([], dtype=int64),)]
```

Values in `redcap_final_arm1_data['record_id']` are unique.

**Question:** I want to get all row numbers (index) of `redcap_final_arm1_data['record_id']` in `ahk_ids_new`  where `redcap_final_arm1_data['record_id']` has the same value as any values in `arm_1_and_m1_df['record_id']`. How to do that?

Expected output (content) of `ahk_ids_new`:

```
Out[57]: [0, 3, 2, 9]
```

*If there is a better way to do what I need with data frames from my code please post your better variant instead of fixing my code.*

Comment: Please post your expected output so it is easier for us to help you

Comment: @JuanC Thank you. Done.

Comment: @jfaccioni It should be `[0, 3, 2, 9]`. Sorry, I am coming from R where index starts from `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `isin` and slicing on index

```
a_index = (redcap_final_arm1_data.index[redcap_final_arm1_data.record_id
                                           .isin(arm_1_and_m1_df.record_id)].tolist())
```

output:

```
Out[1355]: [0, 2, 3, 9]
```